# Internal searcing put into google analytics

Tags: lucene, google-analytics

I am in need of implementing google analytics on a site where i have my own search functionality, and i would like to have the ability to tell analytics what the users are searching in the internal seaching, so i can catch the search terms and other interesting stuff.

So the buttom line is that when the users are searching with the internal search, this should be shown inside google analytics, which terms they used, which page them came to and so on.. All the stuff that google's own search implements.

Others must have done this, but i can't find the right information.

thanks in advance!

Comment: Frankly thata's all in the site search reports (and related) - https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1012264?hl=env

Comment: @EikePierstorff It is.. But we have our own search on the site, just want to connect it to analytics.. So i need to go around site search.

Comment: Still not clear what you are asking (tracking your own internal search is what site search tracking is for). Or do you say that your engine is not an internal search but a web search ?

Comment: Dont know if i have misunderstood what the google site search really is. But to clearify my needs.. I have a search feature on the site. I just want analytics to know about the results and terms of this search. So add something so google analytics listens to MY search. came across something called Custom Search Engine, which seems like, it does the trick ?

Comment: In the admin section for a Analytics view (profile) you can set a parameter that is used by your site search - let's say  the parameter is "q" (and is either transmitted via the Get method in the Url or you need to pass it via a virtual pageview in the search result page). So somebody calls search?q=foo. Then "foo" will turn up in the site search->keywords report in the "Behavior" section where you can crossreference visits with "foo" as internal search keyword with any other metric from the Google tracking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As **Eike Pierstorff** mentioned in his comment, within the interface you can set GA to look for a parameter in the URL. So if your site search already passes the search term as a query string parameter, just set GA to look for that parameter and you should be good to go.

If your site search does not push the search term to a query string parameter (e.g. it's AJAX based or simply doesn't do it), you can push it to the `_trackPageview` call.

**Example:**

```
// do what you have to do to populate this variable with the search term
var searchTerm='search term here'; 
var pageName = location.pathname+location.search;
pageName += (location.search) ? '&' : '?';
pageName += 'q='+searchTerm;
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', pageName])
```

Then in the GA interface, set GA to look for the "q" parameter.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do it is to send a custom **Event** whenever your search button is pressed or when the results are shown.
Add the search string as the **Event Label**.

You will then see the website searches on the Behavior->Events section.